# Build error in visual studio "Error 102: The "___" task was not found."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, ide

I am using visual studio and I have a problem building my project. I am not sure how to fix it.

I am getting this error:

```
Error   289 The "CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\wix2010.targets   1279    6   ProcedureManagerSetup
```

I double click this error and this leads me to this chunk of code:

```
  <Target
    Name="AddProjectReferenceDefineConstants"
    Condition=" '@(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths)' != '' ">

    <CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants
      ProjectReferencePaths="@(_ResolvedProjectReferencePaths)"
      ProjectConfigurations="$(VSProjectConfigurations)">

      <Output TaskParameter="DefineConstants" PropertyName="ProjectReferenceDefineConstants" />
    </CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants>
  </Target>
```

It is specifically pointing to the line:

```
<CreateProjectReferenceDefineConstants
```

Ever since my windows 10 updated, this happened. I noticed though that before, it was using .NET 3.5 . After the update, It changed into .NET 4.0 . I am not sure if this is the main reason why this is happening but it is worth a mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem:

1. open en_visual_studio_professional_2012_x86_dvd_920779
2. press repair
3. open VS2012.5
4. press repair
5. uninstall and install wix2010
6. reboot computer

Answer (score 0):

You add follow key your registry.

Open regedit (You wrote regedit in Run inbox)

and you find HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application folder

and  you add new folder.

> Your new folder name:
>   “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\ASP.NET
>    4.0.30319”